# STL Vector Exception on Erase in unmanaged code

Tags: vector, c++-cli, unmanaged

This is a static function which is an unmanaged function which I am trying to call from a managed CLR project. But everytime I add the erase an exception happens. Both classes are inside the same project
I keep getting an exception on the erase,

```
    #pragma managed(push, off)
    void MessageContainer::ParseByteStream(UINT8 *buf, int length)
    {
        s_RxBufVector.insert(s_RxBufVector.end(), buf, buf + length);
        if (s_RxBufVector.size() >= sizeof(Msg_Struct) * 2)
        {
            int BytesConsumed = 0;
            s_RxBufIterator = s_RxBufVector.begin();
            while (BytesConsumed < (int)s_RxBufVector.size() - sizeof(Msg_Struct))
            {
                if (ntohl(*((UINT32 *)&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __PREAMBLE_OFFSET])) == PreambleVal)
                {
                    switch (ntohl(*((UINT32 *)&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __COMMAND_ID_OFFSET])))
                    {
                    case eCommandIdRxMsg:
                        if (MsgRx != nullptr)
                            (*MsgRx)(ntohl(*((UINT32*)&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __ID_OFFSET])), ntohs(*((UINT16*)(&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __CHANNEL_OFFSET]))),
                                ntohs(*((UINT16*)&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __LENGTH_OFFSET])), &s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __BUFFER_OFFSET]);
                        break;
                    case eCommandIdCmdAck:
                        if (CmdAck != nullptr)
                            //(*CmdAck())
                            break;
                    case eCommandIdSendAck:
                        if (TxConf != nullptr)
                            //(*TxConf())
                            break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    BytesConsumed += sizeof(Msg_Struct);
                }
                else
                {
                    BytesConsumed++;
                }
            }
            s_RxBufVector.erase(s_RxBufIterator, s_RxBufIterator + BytesConsumed);
        }
    }

private:
        static std::vector<UINT8, std::allocator<UINT8>> s_RxBufVector;
        static std::vector<UINT8>::iterator s_RxBufIterator;
Init()
{
        s_RxBufVector.reserve(4096);
}
```

Is there something wrong with the Vector accessing.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred
```

Break stops here 
        _Adopt(_Right._Myproxy->_Mycont);

Worse is that I was trying to delete 24 Bytes at the beginning when the size is already 48

**EDIT:**

Ok, I found commenting out the code for the callback to the managed code solves the Exception but does not help me either

```
(*MsgRx)(ntohl(*((UINT32*)&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __ID_OFFSET])), ntohs(* (UINT16*)(&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __CHANNEL_OFFSET]))), ntohs(*((UINT16*)&s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __LENGTH_OFFSET])), &s_RxBufVector[BytesConsumed + __BUFFER_OFFSET]);
```

The Callback is declared here

```
delegate void MessageReceivedCallbackDelegate(UInt32 Id, UInt16 Channel, UInt16 len, Byte *data);

MessageContainer::SetMessageRxCB((void*)Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(gcnew MessageReceivedCallbackDelegate(MessageReceived)));

unmanaged       
void MessageContainer::SetMessageRxCB(void *fn)
    {
        MsgRx = (RxCbFn)fn;
    }
```

Seems like the managed code is causing some problems to the vector. Probably something wrong with how I try to call the managed code, I need some hints :)

**SOLVED:**

Ok, I forgot to decorate the delegates

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
delegate void MessageReceivedCallbackDelegate(UInt32 Id, UInt16 Channel, UInt16 Dlc, Byte *data)
```

Comment: 1) `erase` invalidates iterators in a `vector`, and you're calling `erase` with an iterator value that may be invalid. 2) Why don't you output  the index values you're using for the vector?  Or use the `vector::at` function to determine if you're going out of bounds.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to decorate the delegates 

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
 delegate void MessageReceivedCallbackDelegate(UInt32 Id, UInt16 Channel, UInt16 Dlc, Byte *data)